# Minimum laptop requirements for devops learning

Tags: docker, vagrant, virtualization

I started learning devops technologies, but I encountered a problem with my laptop on the first labs, I cant provision more than 3 VMs in Vagrant, and I found out that my processor is not sufficient, so I cant build labs of 6 or more servers ...

Is there a minimum requirement if I have to buy a new laptop ? Am I going to need less/more requirements when I'm going to jump to containers or newer technologies ?

My actual configuration :
CPU : i7-7500U (4xCores 2.7Ghz)
RAM : 8Go

Comment: I guess that upgrading the laptop's RAM should be sufficient (if its possible / supported by the model).

Comment: unfortunately the maximum RAM is 8Go I cant add more

Answer (score 1):

It'll probably really depend on your budget. 8GB RAM seems like very little, as bahrep suggested I would first try to see if your laptop can get a RAM upgrade.

If you can afford it you could also do your experiments in the cloud. It depends on what you want to learn (DevOps is a large field) but chances are you'll have to get acquainted with the cloud. If your current hardware does not allow you to run multiple infrastructures at once I would look into VM/VPS purchasing: you'll get the resources you need and get to learn about major cloud providers in the meantime.

Comment: unfortunately the maximum RAM is 8Go I cant add more

Comment: exactly as you said, devops is a large field, I'm just folowing a roadmap but i was stuck at my first labs :/
Im planning to learn vagrant - docker - ansible - kubernetes - jenkins in this order and not surr what to do after that